# Autohotkey hotstrings too slow? Using Autohotkey for barcode entry and processing

Tags: barcode, autohotkey, barcode-scanner

I'm currently trying to set something up whereby I can use Autohotkey to read a barcode and output a filepath.

My barcode scanner reads a barcode and outputs the result as text (as if it were typed into a keyboard very quickly) followed by the enter key.

I can format my barcodes how I like, and I currently have the following:

```
::**::
input, scan,,{Enter}
If StrLen(scan) <> 11 {
    msgbox There was an error - barcode read was not 11 characters long (= %scan% )
} else 
{
    StringSplit, ScanArray, scan, ~
    ;msgbox Job ID is %ScanArray1%
    ;msgbox Part ID is %ScanArray2%
    strPathString := "z:\jobs\" . ScanArray1 . "\" . ScanArray2 . ".xxl"
send {home}
send {shift down}
send {end}
send {shift up}
send %strPathString%
send {Enter}
}
return
```

The barcodes I'm using are formatted: `** 12345|67890`. If this barcode is scanned, the plan is:

- `**` (including space after asterisks) at the start activates the hotstring.
- `12345|67890` is read into AHK and `strPathString` becomes `z:\jobs\12345\67890.xxl`
- The current line which the cursor rests on before scanning (which should be the load file location box of a program) is selected, deleted, and replaced with strPathString, followed by enter, which loads the file in the necessary program.

Now this works correctly, some of the time, however I'm hitting the issue that once the hotstring fires, it seems to be taking too long to start reading the input, resulting in AHK receiving things like "345|67890" and other results where the first ~1-4 digits are missing. The effect is also worse if my computer/cpu is busy with other things.

If I were to have the user press a hotkey (say ctrl+shift+e) to bring up an InputBox, which then reads and processes the barcode input, it works correctly every time (I have tested this), but I'd rather just have the user position the cursor in the right field, then scan the barcode directly without having to use an InputBox. Also of note is that when an InputBox is active, scanning the barcode with the HotString code still active, and the "** " at the start of the barcode, the hotstring is processed perfectly every time, which is what leads me to believe that it's just a case of AHK's "wake up" time being too slow.

Are there any other ways to do this which will be more reliable?

Comment: Does the scanner send anything prior to the barcode? Something like a dedicated shortcut (e.g. `CTRL+O`)? `Input` relies on the target window to consume the keys, and it fails doing that, `Input` will fail, too. What kind of window is active during the input? Does the window receive all the keystrokes from the scanner if you don't use `Input`? A screenshot as well as data from Window Spy could be helpful.

Comment: The scanner doesn't inherently send any special prefix but I'm trying to set one up now. The active window for input is just a standard File>Open dialog, and I don't think it makes a difference since the same thing happens if I have my active cursor on a notepad window.

Comment: Does notepad receive the whole string? Also, how exactly is the order of events when you use the script? Do you start the hotstring and then read the barcode? Another thing i'm suspicous about is the `StringSplit`. Why do you use `~` as delimiter if the numbers are sparated by `|`?

Comment: If I disable AHK then notepad receives the full string every time. Although my barcode is supposedly split by a pipe ( | ) notepad and AHK receive a tilde ( ~ ) and this works correctly. With AHK running and the hotstring active, notepad does not always receive the full string and instead the messagebox in my code pops up and tells me what's been received by AHK. Occasionally the first couple of digits of the barcode will be sent to notepad before the msgbox comes up.

Comment: Ah, I got it now. A simple solution could be to put `SetBatchLines, -1` on top of your script. Please let me know me if that's enough. Otherwise, I will post an answer proposing another way I have in mind. Edit: Additionally, put `#InstallKeybdHook` on the top of your script.

Comment: That seems like it might be better, but it still fails about a quarter of the time. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this piece of code using [RegEx powered hotstrings](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/15015-regex-powered-dynamic-hotstrings/).

```
#Include Hotstrings.ahk
SetBatchLines, -1

; Not sure, whether to put "|" or "~" as delimiter here
hotstrings("\*\* (\d{5})\|(\d{5})", "ProcessBarcode")

ProcessBarcode:
    msgbox % "Job ID: " $1 "`nPart ID: " $2
return
```

Comment: Many thanks. I had to make some small changes though to get it working correctly - please see my answer below.

Comment: @WhatEvil Silly mistake by me. I've escaped the meta characters. There shouldn't be the need to change your barcodes.

Comment: OK, well my answer is slightly more complete, and the actual input format for the barcodes is trivial in this instance, but it's good to know about escaping the chars.

Answer (score 0):

Made some small changes:

```
Process, priority, , High  ; Have the script set itself to high priority - seems to help.

#InstallKeybdHook

#Include C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoHotkey\Extras\Scripts\Hotstrings.ahk
SetBatchLines, -1

hotstrings("!! (\d{5})!(\d{5})", "ProcessBarcode")

Return ; return before the barcode processing starts makes sure that ProcessBarcode doesn't autoexec on script load.

ProcessBarcode:
    a := $1
    b := $2 
    strPathString := "z:\Jobs\" . a . "\" . b . ".xxl"
    sendmode Input ; This makes the string sending quicker.
    send {home}
    send {shift down}
    send {end}
    send {shift up}
    send %strPathString%
    send {Enter}
return
```

Note: The script doesn't seem to like characters like `*`, `~` in the hotstring, so I have used ! as my key/separation character, which is handled correctly.

This all seems to work correctly, for now. Many thanks.

Comment: I tried #Include <LibName> but it wouldn't go for it. Do you know what the default directory is? I tried My Documents and the AutoHotkey folder (including the scripts subdirectory). Also I have disabled setting the process priority now, but if I disable keybdhook then the scanning is no longer reliable. Also whether I use ControlSend or ControlSetText it is also sending part/all of the barcode input (so `!! 12345!67890`) to the control field, if I have the control field currently selected. How do I stop that?

Comment: I'm using `ControlSetText, Edit1, %strPathString%, Select program to run` but when I have the cursor in Edit1 it's actually sending: `Z:\Jobs\12345\67890.xxl!! 12345!67890`. If I have the cursor in notepad then it still leaves a `!` behind, but does then send the text correctly to the Edit1 field in my desired program.

Comment: Still doesn't work correctly. Now it works correctly when the focus isn't in the Edit1 control (i.e. there is no `!` left behind if I'm in notepad) but it seems to still be malfunctioning when it the focus is in my open file dialog. I've even added `ControlGetFocus, strCtrlFocus, Select program to run` then `if ErrorLevel = 0` to change behaviour based on whether the window is in focus or not, but it's just not working. I think I need to buy a better barcode scanner where I can turn off the `ENTER` suffix. Unless you have other ideas?

Comment: Well `Input` was what I was using originally which was too slow. Or do you mean something else? Can you elaborate at all on this or the `Sleep` thing?

Comment: I mean in the subroutine for the hotstring `!! (\d{5})!(\d{5})`, you put something like `Input, tmp, , {Enter}`. Maybe this will get rid of the `ENTER`. Isn't the sent suffix the problem here? Alternatively, you could use a rather long  `Sleep` instead of `Input` for testing purposes.

Comment: OK well for some reason it all just seemed to stop working completely, even the code which was previously working. I think it may be due to a cheap scanner. I've now bought a new scanner (made by Opticon, who seem to have a good range of setting options) and set it up so that `Ctrl+D` is sent before each barcode. It seems that having a single character (or keypress combo) speeds the input up for AHK greatly, whereas hotstrings take a small amount of time to actually trigger and start accepting further input. Thanks for all your help @MCL

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here is what I've ended up using.

Note that I bought a new and more configurable scanner (Opticon OPI-3601) which I was able to setup to send `CTRL+D` at the start of each barcode string, and it seems that a single key (or key-combo) triggers the script to start accepting input instantly, or at least quickly enough to catch the output from my barcode reader.

```
#InstallKeybdHook

SetBatchLines, -1 


^d::
input, scan,,{Enter} ;start accepting input from barcode reader
If (StrLen(scan) <> 11) {
    msgbox There was an error - barcode read was not 11 characters long (= %scan% )
} else {
    StringSplit, ScanArray, scan, ~ ; split the string into an array 
    strPathString := "z:\George's Jobs\CHC\Barcode xilog testing\" . ScanArray1 . "\" . ScanArray2 . ".xxl" ; path will need to be changed to final job folder
    ControlGetFocus, strCtrlFocus, Select program to run ; check if the "Select program to run" window is in focus.
    If (ErrorLevel = 0) { ; if program window is in focus, send keys and path directly
        sendmode input ; faster sending
        send {home}
        send {shift down}
        send {end}
        send {shift up} ; selects current text in input field
        send %strPathString%
        send {Enter}
    } else {
        ControlSetText, Edit1, %strPathString%, Select program to run
        ControlSend, Edit1, {Enter}, Select program to run
    }
}
return
```

I'm unsure if the keyboard hook or `SetBatchLines` are still necessary, but they don't seem to hurt.